Can you deep fry soaked but uncooked whole chickpeas or are there safety or other issues that makes this a bad idea?
I make falafels the traditional way, grind up soaked but uncooked chickpeas/fava, add minced onion, garlic, etc. and then form and fry.
All the recipes I've found for crispy fried chickpeas start with cooked or canned chickpeas but is there any reason you can't or shouldn't deep fry soaked but uncooked chickpeas?
It works for falafel.

I suspect that just soaked chickpeas will never get cooked if just fried so that you have the choice of uncooked or burned. In falafel the chickpeas are much finer ground and are fried for several minutes.

Try it! It's a cheap experiment and there's no risk!

@jmk That was my thought too, either that or rock-hard.

@beausmith yup, i'm doing the experiment now, as you said it's cheap and I was too curious to wait for a possible answer here. i'll update with an answer later today. I soaked 50g of chickpeas in cold water last night, i'm cooking 50g of chickpeas now in water. I'll fry both batches at 160C for I'm assuming 2 to 4 minutes but i'll judge both batches on colour for done-ness.

@jmk I'm not too worried about the cooking time, falafel are much bigger so it would take longer for the heat to penetrate than a whole chickpea. I am thinking though, that the extra water in the onion and herbs might be necessary for the cooking process. i'll know for sure in an hour or two!

Yes you can deep fry soaked, uncooked chickpeas and get a nearly identical result to deep frying pre-cooked or canned chickpeas.
I did an experiment: soaked 50g of dry chickpeas overnight, the next day cooked 50g of dry chickpeas in boiling water until tender but not soft (about 45 minutes).
Both batches were drained and dried on a clean tea towel to remove surface moisture (soaked chickpeas weighed 85g, boiled were 90g).
Heated oil to 160C, fried the boiled batch first (all the recipes I've seen call for pre-cooked or canned chickpeas). After 5 minutes there was not much browning but the bubbling had reduced a lot so I drained onto a paper towel and sprinkled with salt. Fried weight was 51g.
Brought the oil back up to temp, fried the soaked (but not cooked) batch for 5 minutes, drained, and salted. Fried weight was 51g, same as for the pre-cooked batch.
The texture was close to identical for both batches, the pre-cooked ones felt marginally more floury on the inside but I might have been looking for differences. The soaked but uncooked tasted better because I was more heavy handed with the salt. They also weren't as crispy as I hoped, next time I'll fry at 180C.
I don't know you'll get the same result if cooked in an oven or counter-top convection oven.

Excellent, nice to see a self-answer.
